# Extracting HTML Data with BS4 loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to loop through a dataframe I have with roughly 1000 rows. For each row a website is called. So far so good. However, when i try to extract a specific data entry from the website, it stops working after 100 loops, sometimes after 300 loops. My current code is:

```
for i in rows:
url = "https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/products/investment-products/discount-certificates/stuttgart/{}".format(i)
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
first_day = soup.find("dt", text="First exchange day").findNext('dd').string
```

rows is my dataframe which i use. I always get the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'". Is there something wrong with my tag search?  The data entry I need is inside the dd tag but has now specific name for which I can search directly as far as I can tell. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs when you try to find the data in the row in which it does not exist.

```py
for i in rows:
    url = "https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/products/investment-products/discount-certificates/stuttgart/{}".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    try:
        first_day = soup.find("dt", text="First exchange day").findNext('dd').string
    except:
        print('The required data does not exist in this row')
```

Doing the above changes would enable you to extract data if it is available else it will just print that data is not available. You can alternatively use `if-else` too but this is the easiest method.

Comment: This really helped! The code works now and I can actually use it. Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'` because you're calling `.findNext()` on something that doesn't exist.

If there isn't a `dt` element on the page with the text `First exchange day`, then this line

`soup.find("dt", text="First exchange day")`

returns `None`. You get the error when you try and call `.findNext()` on this `None` value.

You need to add a check in, making sure that you actually managed to find the `dt` element on the page; if you find it, then do `findNext()`. If you don't, skip that one.

Comment: yes, thank you so much. Your answer and Atharva's solved my problem so I can work with it. I'm completely new to coding and actually used a check at another point in my code but somehow couldn't translate it to this problem. Anyway, thanks again!